# Problems with Conky's ${eval}

Tags: conky

I'm trying to do something with ${eval} in Conky, but I'm having problems even with a minimal example:

`${eval ${exec echo '${font DejaVu Sans Mono :size=6}hey!'}}`

As far as I understand, I would believe that I should see the string "hey!" printed with the 'DejaVu Sans Mono' font, but instead I'm getting this as output:

`${font DejaVu Sans Mono :size=6}hey!`

I want to be able to execute something as I would in the terminal, and then parse that as a Conky statement. Isn't the whole idea of $eval to parse that string again? If so, am I doing something wrong, am I misunderstanding how it works, or is that a bug in $eval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong with `${eval}` and nobody in the Conky's chat was able to explain it to me, but they suggested using `${execpi}` and it did exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

I got here with the same problem. In your example you need to replace `exec` with `execp` inside `eval` for it to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
${font DejaVu Sans Mono :size=6}${exec echo 'hey!'}
```

Conky formatting is not nested like HTML. Instead you set a formatting and it sticks until you change it. So, first we set the font and size (`${font DejaVu Sans Mono :size=6}`), and then we tell it what to output (`${exec echo 'hey!'}`), which is in this case the output of the command `echo 'hey'`.

So, if I put this

```
 ${font DejaVu Sans Mono :size=6}${font DejaVu Sans Mono :size=20}${exec echo 'hey!'}
```

'hey' would be printed in  size 20 and the size 6 would be essentially useless. Hopefully that clears things up.

Comment: My example was just a simplified one. I don't actually need to have a ${font} in there but more complicated stuff. The question is aimed to execute something and then parse it.